# Confusion on database calls In OOP, MVC, (Java)

Tags: java, oop, model-view-controller

Let's say we store the instances of the classes `Monkey` and `Banana` in a database, we want too do this to obtain low coupling.

Why is it not good practices to save an instance (database calls) in those classes and is there a better/other way to handle the database calls?

I am new too the MVC concept and looked in to something called dbhandler:

[image]

But I don't see why it would not be better to just save the database calls in those instances.

Comment: You store objects in a database so you can access them later, persistency has nothing to do with low coupling. What do you mean with “save database calls”?

Comment: Sorry i was thinking that for me it seemed that I would obtain low coupling if I  save the instance precisely in those classes, since they have the information that shall be saved instead of saving it somewhere else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me it's all about separation of concerns. Each object should have one, and only one, single, responsibility. So your models are there to represent each table in the database. In your example, there will be a `Monkey` `POJO` that represents a table monkey in your database. Let's say you write all your SQL queries in your POJO's, everything is fine for the first few months then your team decides that they need to migrate to a different db vendor which doesn't fully support your SQL syntax, now what? Basically you've married your code to a db vendor. Also code that deals with databases is usually dense, long, and repetitive.

Moreover by pushing the data retrieval to another layer, you can also have a "db" that might not be a db, say a few csv files for (bad) example, but you get the point, your design is more flexible. To the developer the database is a datasource that he/she interacts via a common, stable, `interface` without needing to know the intricacies of that given db.

One more thing, there are four common operations that you usually do in a database, those are Create, Read, Delete, Update (CRUD) so by pushing all the database logic to its own layer, you can write less code in two places:

1. The data layer: since you have repetitive CRUD operations
2. Your POJO's are simple plain data with setter/getters

PS: Maybe the biggest benefit of breaking these two layers, application and data, is that you can use tools like [ORMs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping) to auto generate all of your data access layer then you only focus on developing the app and you can swap, modify, alter, your database with more ease.